# How do I resend data from previous url after reCAPTCHA passed in the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

Data sent from this

www.example.com/modules/liaise/index.php?form_id=xxx

In normal condition, after submit, the page redirects to

www.example.com/modules/liaise/index.php

and sends mail.

Wantedly, I placed the reCAPTCHA in the same file (index.php).

Google captcha :

```
require_once "recaptchalib.php";
// your secret key
$secret = "secret key";

// empty response
$response = null;

// check secret key
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);
// if submitted check response
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
    $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
}

if ($response != null && $response->success) {

//send mail

} else {

echo '
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
    <div id="html_element"></div>
    <script>
    var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render("html_element", {
          "sitekey" : "sitekey",
          "callback" : correctCaptcha
        });
      };
    var correctCaptcha = function(response) {

        location.reload();

    };
    </script>';
}
```

Whenever I pass reCAPTCHA and page reloads, reCAPTCHA shows again.
I know data from previous page www.example.com/modules/liaise/index.php?form_id=xxx is still there by using

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
    {
    echo "$key=$value";
}
```

Is there any way by which I can resend data from previous url after reCAPTCHA is passed in the same page?
I am newbie in coding. Please be specific.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about re-sending your data as mail you can use something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['form-input'])) {
  // Send mail
}
```

and every time you reload the page and the Post data is not null or blank, it will run that code.

If you are wanting the `reCAPTCHA` to reload as success, I would say that's defeats the security of `reCAPTCHA`

Also I see that you have a typo `esle` should be `else`.